# Sequelize query is giving TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using express and sequelize for my node application. On the controller file, I have the following:

```
var models          = require('../models'),
    Property        = models.property,
    Sequelize       = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(req, res){
  Sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM 'property'", { type:Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
   .then(function(properties) {
      res.json(properties)
  })
}
```

I can use model.findAll fine but when I try to use raw query, I'm getting the TypeError: undefined is not a function. Can you point what I'm doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to be calling `query()` on a *`Sequelize` instance* instead:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM 'property'", { type:Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
   .then(function(properties) {
      res.json(properties)
  })
```

Comment: The typeerror is gone but now I'm getting this: Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "'property'". Any thoughts?

Comment: @iMad sure, remove the single quotes around the `property`.

Comment: still not a function in the seeder/migration up() method. How is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
const sql = "select * from ..."

 model.sequelize.query(sql, { type: model.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
.then(function (rows) {
    ... do a job on the query here...   
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was reading the contents of a file and importing it in a migration with:

```
const sqlFile = fs.readFileSync(file, {encoding: "UTF-8"});

await queryInterface.sequelize.query(sqlFile, {          
            raw: true,
            type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW
          });
```

But I was receiving the error:
`Error importing:  sql.trim is not a function`.

Long story short, my SQL contained the **`** (backquote/backtick) character, and I needed to escape it.

So I escaped it as soon as I read the file:

```
const sqlFile = fs.readFileSync(file, {encoding: "UTF-8"}).replace('`', '\`');
```

Problem solved. But it took me a bit over an hour to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you for this - just hit this today. Finding good examples of ```queryInterface.sequelize.query``` within a migration has been difficult.