# How to import sequelize js to perform a raw query

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to run a `raw` query in the Sequelize js.

This is my query in my banner.js `controller` file

```
const sequelize = require("sequelize");

const data = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM banners", {
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
      });
```

But I got an error saying:

```
TypeError: sequelize.query is not a function
```

Why could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638476/sequelize-query-is-giving-typeerror-udefined-is-not-a-function)

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM 'property'", { type:Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
   .then(function(properties) {
      res.json(properties)
  })
```

Comment: First I see that answer but I think pass the same instance is the elegant way to do that. Anyways thanks a lot for your help. =)

Comment: I have added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to instantiate sequelize with your connection details.

and this is not just mean that you need to create an instance inside your controller. But you have to pass the db instance to the controller in a way that you can refer the `db.sequlize` inside your controller.