# sequelize.query() throws Unhandled rejection

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I get a

```
error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise {"_bitField":18087936,"_fulfillmentHandler0":{}}
```

at

```
var Query = [
          `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${table1};`,
          `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${table2};`
        ];
sequelize.query(Query).then(result => {
          console.log(result);
        });
```

what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Always use catch block when handling promises.

```
      `sequelize.query(Query).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(error =>  console.log(error));`
```

Comment: now this happens TypeError: sql.trim is not a function

Comment: Refer this article to resolve the issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638476/sequelize-query-is-giving-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Must set multipleStatements = true when creating a connection:

```
new Sequelize(..., {
  dialectOptions: {
    multipleStatements: true
  }
})
```