# Sequelize.query is not a function

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

Can't get Sequelize.query(...) to work. The error I get is,

```
TypeError: Sequelize.query is not a function
```

But I am requiring 'sequelize' at the beginning of this file tasks.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var express = require("express")
var router = express.Router()
const Task = require("../model/Task")

//Get task
router.get("/tasks", (req, res) => {

  Sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM physics_tbls")
    .then(tasks => {
    console.log("All tasks:", JSON.stringify(tasks, null, 4));
    res.json(tasks)
  })
    .catch(err => {
    res.send("error: " + err)
  })

})
```

Task.js creates the model,

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize")
const db = require("../database/db.js")

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
  "physics_tbls", {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    Level: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    Level_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    Year: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    Question: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    Answer: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    Topic: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    Sub_topic: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    Question_type: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    Marks: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    Question_number: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    Part: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    Sub_part: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false
  }
)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look here: [Sequelize query is giving TypeError: undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638476/sequelize-query-is-giving-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function)

Comment: if you are using sequelize-cli, import sequelize from `const { sequelize } = require('./model/index.js');` since this instance is the one connected to the database and has the query function.